# getting all the security profiles created for an entity ms dynamics

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

How can I get all the security profiles created for an entity? Is there any API through which I can get the ids or any information about the security profiles which had been created for that entity?

I am able to get all the security roles that had been assigned to a particular user. I want to compare the security profile ids of an entity and the user. If they match, I will check if the security profile has given the user read access to the records found in that entity and the user will be given visibility access to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want to get this info for your reporting or overview, There is an [XRM toolbox plugin called Entity security plugin](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/Entity_Security_Plugin/)

This will give you for an entity which security role has what access.